# Traveling salesman ampl

Tags: ampl

I am working on a Traveling salesman problem and can't figure how to solve it. The problem contains ten workers, ten workplaces where they should be driven to and one car driving them one by one. There is a cost of $1.5 per km. Also, all the nodes (both workers and workplaces) are positioned in a 10*10 matrix and the distance between each block in the matrix is 1 km.
The problem should be solved using AMPL.

I have already calculated the distances between each coordinate in excel and have copy pasted the matrix to the dat.file in AMPL.

```
 This is my mod.file so far (without the constrains): 

    param D > 0;
    param D > 0;
    set A = 1..W cross 1..D; 

    var x{A};   # 1 if the route goes from person p to work d, 
               # 0 otherwise

    param cost;
    param distance;

    minimize Total_Cost:
        sum {(w,d) in A} cost * x[w,d];
```

Comment: How does x specify a route? It identifies which people go to which workplace, but not in which order. You may want to look for a representation which corresponds better to what you're trying to find.

Comment: Good point, I also forgot to write that x is supposed to be binary, this is because the car should not drive the same route twice. 
The problem is also that all the routes are specified, but not the routes between them, so I don't know how I am supposed to write that in AMPL. Also I know that the solution is ment to be be solvable in AMPL only, and that the calculated distances from excel doesn't need to be made, but I thought this might be easier. 
Need a lot of help...

Comment: I'm not quite clear on the problem here. Is each worker assigned to a specific job already, or is that assignment part of the question? Can the car pick up more than one worker at once, or does it need to drop each one at their workplace before picking up the next?

Comment: Each worker is assigned to a specific job, yes. There is one car picking up one worker and drops him of at his workplace before picking up the next one. 

We have managed to find a route now, but cant find out how to eliminate the subtours. 
Thank you for response!!

Answer (score 2):

OK, so your route looks like: start-worker 1-job 1-worker 2-job 2-worker 3-job-3-...-job 10-end (give or take start & end points, depending on how you formulate the problem.

That being the case, the "worker n-job n" parts of your route are predetermined. You don't need to include "worker n-job n" costs in the route optimisation, because there's no choice about those parts of the route (though you do need to remember them for calculating total cost, of course).

So what you have here is really a basic TSP with 10 "destinations" (each representing a single worker and their assigned job) but with an asymmetric cost matrix (because cost of travel from job i to worker j isn't the same as cost of travel from job j to worker i).

If you already have an implementation for the basic TSP, it should be easy to adapt. If not, then you need to write one and make that small change for an asymmetric cost matrix. I've seen two different approaches to this in AMPL.

### 2-D decision matrix with subtour elimination

Decision variable x{1..10,1..10} is defined as: x[i,j] = 1 if the route goes from job i to job j, and 0 otherwise. Constraints require that every row and column of this matrix has exactly one 1.

The challenging part with this approach is preventing subtours (i.e. the "route" produced is actually two or more separate cycles instead of one large cycle). It sounds like your current attempt is at this stage.

One solution to the problem of subtours is an iterative approach:

1. Write an implementation that includes all requirements except for subtour prevention.
2. Solve with this implementation.
3. Check the resulting solution for subtours.
4. If no subtours are found, return the solution and end.
5. If you do find subtours, add a constraint which prevents that particular subtour. (Identify the arcs involved in the subtour, and set a constraint which implies they can't all be selected.) Then go to #2.

For a small exercise you may be able to do the subtour elimination by hand. For a larger exercise, or if your lecturer doesn't like that approach, you can create a .run that automates it. See Bob Fourer's post of 31/7/2013 in [this thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/ampl/mVsFg4mAI1c) for an example of implementation.

### 3-D decision matrix with time dimension

Under this approach, you set up a decision variable x{1..10,1..10,1..10} where x[i,j,t] = 1 if the route goes from job i to worker j *at time t*, and 0 otherwise. Your constraints then require that the route goes to and from each job/worker combination exactly once, that if it goes *to* worker i at time t then it must go *from* job i at time t+1 (excepting first/last issues), that it's doing exactly one thing at time t, and that the endpoint at time 10 matches the startpoint at time 1 (assuming you want a circuit).

This prevents subtours, because it forces a route that starts at some point at time 1, returns to that point at time 10, and doesn't visit any other point more than once - meaning that it has to go through all of them exactly once.

Comment: Thank you, this was extremely helpful!!